# VBA - Duplicate Worksheet by Existing Listing until end of the list

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA code where this code fails on the last code.

I got this code through the website source.

**Here is the description:**

1. Sheet "Skywalker" is data from system.
2. Sheet "Generate" is to check the list of amounts that need
   to be issued by the report through the formula that has been set.
3. Sheet "Generate" on B3 is the place of the button to press (green
   color). After reading on `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet` macro failed.

**Here is the code and template example**

**sample template**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GWqOfZFpiay0NVP-mXQfjGEc4UEqCzKn?usp=sharing

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range


Set MyRange = Sheets(4).Range("C6")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets(5).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
Next MyCell


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Sub
```

What do I need to do so that macros do not debug ?.

I need a message box when the macro is done.

I really appreciate your help. TQ

sorry for my bad eng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is causing for empty cell. In your formula output there is no data to some cells. So when the code trying to renaming sheets with null then error is happening. You need to stop macro when loop comes to this null value cell, Use a `IF --- Else` logic to check empty cell and exit sub on this point. Try below codes and let us know your feedback.

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets(4).Range("C6")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If MyCell.Value = "" Then 'Check for null/empty value cell.
            Exit Sub 'If reach to null cell then exit sub.
        Else
            Sheets(5).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
        End If
    Next MyCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hai thanks for help. the code smooth running... Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggyback off of Harun24HR's code, I would add a Goto statement instead of "Exit Sub". The list that was provide had 8 rows (rows 6-13) of values and the rest as null values. What if there is a scenario where row 14 is null and row 15 has a value? As such, we want to use the Goto statement to handle this situation.

Here is the revised code of Harun24HR:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets(4).Range("C6")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If MyCell.Value = "" Then 'Check for null/empty value cell.
            GoTo NextOne: 'Go to next MyCell
        Else
            Sheets(5).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
        End If NextOne:
    Next MyCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Macro is done" 'Insert your own message between the quotations. 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. The code stuck at < End If NextOne: > but its ok i already fix. to next MyCell. Thanks a lot.